# Why does the BCL use signed int for many methods, when in many cases an unsigned type would be more appropriate?

Tags: c#, .net

As far as you're looking at, these days I've faced a little curiosity about why the basic functions, belonging to subordinate namespaces from `System`, have typically `int` type parameters in most cases when they need to specify the ones to number type.

For example, here is a declaration of `Task.Delay` (that below is at when to suppose the System.Threading.Tasks namespace is used through `using` keyword).

```
Task Task.Delay (int millisecondsDelay, ...);
```

Well, if you have already read the document for that method written by Microsoft, I know you might try to correct the question of me because that the first param of it is specified as -1 means to stop doing a task indefinitely so that the `int` type is inevitable for this case.

However many other methods are done similarly, which signifies the ways of the action are not different, even though they don't seem to have to uniquely deal with that `int` type, not the others. So what I'd like to ask is, whether functions must take `int` factors although there are a lot of alternatives, `uint`, `short`, `ushort`, `byte`, and `sbyte`.

Comment: [CLS Compliance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components#cls-compliance-rules) drove a lot of early decisions, which is why half the types you mention wouldn't be used - "unsigned integers other than Byte are not CLS-compliant"

Comment: `int` is generally used unless there's as strong reason to use a different numeric type. This generally makes life easier: you're not casting between different representations of an integer all of the time.

Comment: I understand it. I did never know that unsigned integer types are not compliant on CLS so they cannot be a better choice than `int` universally to make someone's own methods at a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned type isn't used in .NET Framework because these types aren't [CLS Complianct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components#cls-compliance-rules).
CLS Compliance is necessary to write a library that works in all .NET Language (C#, VB.NET, F#, ...).
If you use unsigned type, you can see this type of [warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797648/net-framework-argument-type-uint-is-not-cls-compliant-on-p-invoke) :

> Argument of type 'uint' is not CLS-compliant

When .NET was released (2002), the most common processor architecture was on 32 bit. It's again currently the case (all device in ARM like smartphone, watch, TV, car, ...).

`Int32` (alias `int` in C#) provide the higher range value for the best best performance (directly supported by processor). Now the Framework is released and used, it isn't possible to change this. But it's sufficient for most needs.

Edit : I don't work for Microsoft, it's just supposition.